# Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager (SCCM) scans GUID from BIOS?

Tags: windows, bios

A customer is planning to use SCCM (Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager). According to them, the software is looking for a GUID (Globally unique identifier) in BIOS but found out the the fields are filled with same string.

As a result, they could not use SCCM. According to them SCCM also scans for MAC address on the motherboard.

- Is GUID referring to UUID in the BIOS?
- Is there a way to get SCCM to work w/o using GUID. Could SCCM use Mac addresses as Unique identifier? since Mac address is unique too?

Comment: Looks like there aren't a lot of SCCM folk hanging around here.  You might have better luck at the dedicated MS forum, http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/configmgrgeneral/threads

Comment: Thank you Harry Johnston, your suggestion is really useful. I will try posting the questions at the link suggested by you earlier. Have a nice day =)

Comment: We found out from customer that he was referring to GUID listed on the "PXE boot agent" screen. We double-checked and found out that the GUID string mentioned is actually referring to UUID string in SMBIOS =).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what SCCM would be looking for in your (customer's) case, and "GUID" can represent a pretty broad idea; essentially just a way to identify things uniquely.

I've never personally seen any BIOS field labelled specifacilly as "GUID", or a field that follows the usual MS GUID layout (32 digit random alphanumeric string), but many motherboard manufacturers (Intel for example) offer tools to fill in [SMBIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_BIOS) fields like Asset tags, System Serial numbers, Chassis Part numbers, and such.  Which are intended to be used by network management software (like SCCM) for identification and tracking.

Example of OEM software for setting these type of BIOS fields: [Intel® Integrator Assistant](http://www.intel.com/design/motherbd/software/iia/index.htm)

You will need to get something similar from your motherboard's manufacturer.

Comment: Dear Techie007, thank you so much for your feedback. We do have SMBIOS tool that could write to SMBIOS. However, we do not usually write to any field unless requested by customer. For another customer, we put system serial number on one of the specific fields based on their request (they are using Intel AMT). I believe the closest thing for this is "UUID" field in SMBIOS. If that is the case, we may have to remotely use some tool to write the data to SMBIOS on the existing systems that does not have any unique data on SMBIOS. For future orders, we will input the data in advance. Thank you =)

Comment: We found out from customer that he was referring to GUID listed on the "PXE boot agent" screen. We double-checked and found out that the GUID string is actually the same as the UUID string in SMBIOS =). That answered the first question =).